# Reason for differences in Princess and the Goblin editions

Tags: publishing, george-macdonald

[This review](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1495249247) on Amazon.com by Laustic notes that there are two editions of George MacDonald's *The Princess and the Goblin*. The original edition contains italicized interruptions to the story, consisting of dialog between the author and the reader, rather like the asides in *Winnie the Pooh* or *The Princess Bride*. The original version begins:

> There was once a little princess who—
>
> *"But, Mr. Author, why do you always write about princesses?"*
>
> *"Because every little girl is a princess."*

However, most editions published today leave out these interruptions, including editions that claim to be "[original unabridged](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1495249247)". The version most commonly published today begins:

> There was once a little princess whose father was king over a great country full of mountains and valleys.

Laustic notes:

> Two similar occasions where the narrator is interrupted are also removed from the short version, one in Chapter 3 and one at the very end...The long version is the version originally printed in 1872, but the short version was being printed within MacDonald's lifetime. Did he change his mind and cut them out? Did his publishers do it? No one seems to know.

Were these changes a result of MacDonald's edits, rather like [Tolkien rewriting how Bilbo got the ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit#Revisions) in later editions, or did the publishers decide to remove these sections?

Comment: I award you the honorary title of First Person to Ask About George MacDonald.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Project Gutenberg has both versions available. http://www.gutenberg.org/files/34339/34339-h/34339-h.htm has the author asides and appears to be "Copyright, 1920, by David McKay Company".

Comment: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/708 doesn't have the asides, but also has no publisher notice that I can find. Oddly enough, ISFDB doesn't have the McKay version listed.